# How to send audio over HDMI without treating it as a separate display?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, hdmi

I have a 4k monitor connected via DisplayPort and an audio receiver connected via HDMI. The receiver is too old to support 4k, so I can't just pass through video to the display - they need to be connected to the PC separately. The problem is that I can't seem to configure GNOME to treat the receiver as not being another display. Basically there are three options in Settings → Displays:

- "Join Displays", meaning I now have an invisible off-screen trap.
- "Mirror", meaning I *have to* run the monitor at the much lower max pass-through resolution of the receiver.
- "Single Display" using the 4k monitory, which means the receiver doesn't show up as a sink in PulseAudio.

One possible solution would be if there's some way to join the displays but set the X/Y coordinates the same so that both outputs run at their native resolutions. I believe this *used* to be possible, but in GNOME 3 the displays repel each other. I've also tried `xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --same-as XWAYLAND0`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: It also waists processing power to send the image to both. A work around could be to set the size to 0×0. However I feel that there is a better solution.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor How can I set the size to 0x0? The settings panel doesn't allow arbitrary resolutions, and I don't know of any official CLI tools to change resolution (`xrandr` doesn't work in Wayland).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround mentioned in comments indeed works. With nvidia-settings it pretty easy to do:

1. Select audioreceiver screen and click "Advanced" button;
2. Type "1x1" ("0x0" is not acceptable by the app) in "ViewPortIn" field and in "Panning" field;
3. Click "Apply"

If the nvidia-settings appears offscreen, then press "left arrow" key on the keyboard once, and press "enter" key once. This will confirm video screen changes. You can bring back nvidia-settings to main screen by pressing right click at it on the taskbar.

I haven't yet figured out how to make these changes persistent: restore settings after a restart.

[image: nvidia-settings: step 1]

[image: nvidia-settings: step 2]

[image: nvidia-settings: step 3]